# button below a layout still clickable

Tags: java, android, click, progress-bar

I have a screen with vertical button. nothing fancy but it does the job. One of the button is sign-out. during the sign-out process, I want to display a progress circle... this working but the buttons underneath are still clickable and I do not want to. None of the buttons should be clickable when the loading screen appear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/teal_background"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="-16dp"
        android:paddingRight="-16dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

     ...
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firebase_cloud_messaging_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered_button"
        android:text="Firebase Cloud Messaging"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_signals_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered_button"
        android:text="Vehicle Signals"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notifications_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered_button"
        android:text="Notifications"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_bg_bordered_button"
        android:text="Sign out"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:clickable="false">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp" />



</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Any idea on how to make sure there is no clicks button when loading is `visibile`>
Thankgs

Comment: A quick answer is just to setVisibility = gone to those buttons when ProgressBar is shown

Comment: `button.setClicable(false)` in runtime , or try to add `andorid:clicable = "true"` to ProgressBar

Answer (score 1):

Update your code in xml with attribute clickable = true.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:visibility="visible"
android:clickable="true">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 0):

add two lines to parent view of progressBar

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:clickable="true" //these two lines
    android:focusable="true" //these two lines
    >
    
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp" />
    
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```